# add an extra word to add all my URLs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, asp.net, blogger

I need to add extra word in all my blog link.

I am using blogger.

For example.

The Url is : http://wwww.example.com/post1.html then it will automatic change to http://wwww.example.com/post1.html?extraword

means i need to add in all link ?extraword after my original link.

I have referred [.htaccess add an extra word to add all my URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29946382/htaccess-add-an-extra-word-to-add-all-my-urls) but it about htaccess, but blogger doesn't have htaccess.

so please suggest me a code with javascript, with add some extra word in all my url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one simple way (using jQuery) is this:

```
var word='?extraword';
$('a').each(function(){
    var link=$(this).attr('href');
    $(this).attr('href',link+word);
});
```

just include this little script at the beginning of your jQuery script and it's done.

**UPDATE:**

if the links are added dynamically you must change their `href` attribute after the page is completely loaded:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var word='?extraword';
    $('a').each(function(){
        var link=$(this).attr('href');
        $(this).attr('href',link+word);
    });
});
```

also looking at your blog's code I suggest that you put this script at the **end** of your html code right before the closing `body` tag.

**UPDATE2:**

```
<script>
    $(window).load(function(){
        var word='?extraword';
        $('a').each(function(){
            var thelink=$(this).attr('href');
            $(this).attr('href',thelink+word);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**UPDATE3:**

```
<script>
    $(window).load(function(){
        var word='?extraword';
        $('a').each(function(){
            var thelink=$(this).attr('href');
            $(this).attr('href',thelink+word);
        });
        if(window.location.indexOf(word)<0){
            window.location=window.location+word;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This is my blog http://www.andhrahealthyrecipes.in/ and i have applied your script but it not taking effect.

Comment: are the links added dynamically from somewhere else?

Comment: Sorry , i am unable to understand.

and i used


`window.location.href = '<data:blog.url/>' + '?anyword';` 

It changed all url, but it keep reloading the page.

Comment: I'll write the whole script for you, you just need to copy and paste it at the end of your html code right before the closing `body` tag. `</body>` check out the **update2**

Comment: amazing, working perfect, replacing all link with  ?extraword. 

This is more useful for me, but the main visited page not redirecting to ?extraword. 

it adding in all link in href tag. 

anyways thanks you for helping me.

Comment: check out **UPDATE3** it will check if the current page has the extraword or not, if not then it reloads it with the extraword added at the end of it

Comment: amazing, your a experts, thanks, i keep you in my mind, if i need, i will ask any help. 

But stackoverflow not have PM function.

Comment: new error on code. 

"Error parsing XML, line 2493, column 42: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup." 

On line if(window.location.indexOf(word)<0){

Comment: add this line `word=word.toString();` after this line `var word='?extraword';`

Comment: Can you help me In this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31897059/how-to-fake-a-referral`

Answer (score 2):

In java script you can use concat() to join two strings together.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_string.asp

Comment: i am not good in JavaScript.

if i use window.location = 'http://example.com/' + '?anyword'

then it add to one URL only, but i need for all url.

Comment: This is only a small part of the answer.  I think the OP needs to know how to change link hrefs in the current page.

Comment: If that is the issue then look at this forum post. http://forums.asp.net/t/1695757.aspx?Change+link+href+dynamically+using+javascript That should help out.

Comment: if i use this `window.location = 'http://www.something.in/' + '?anyword'` , then it will redirect only one home page, but i need for all my blog pages.